# Scores are not showing

Tags: bug

Scores for all of the Stack Exchange sites are not showing next to my avatar in upper right section of page. Is this a bug, or is my browser simply broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of the new topbar across the StackExchange sites. If you're zoomed into a page, so there's little or no room for the score, the score won't show.

Try zooming into and out of the page to see what I mean.

- on Windows/Linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out
- on Mac <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out